# Bad Request em Post idHTTP com Delphi

Tags: delphi, post

estou tentando comunicação com a API de um ecommerce e de todas as dezenas de tentativas que
fiz somente recebo como resposta "HTTP request failed 400 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request".

Pelo que me informaram tenho que enviar um post e no **body** informar consumer_key, consumer_secret e code.

Uma coisa importante é que tenho que passar essas informações no body do post e não como parametros.

Testei pelo Postman usando x-www-form-urlencoded, informei a url e coloquei as informações acima no Body e deu certo.

No Delphi estou enviando da forma abaixo:

```
lHTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

StringList := TStringList.Create;
StringStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
StringList.Add('consumer_key = abcdefg');
StringList.Add('&consumer_secret = hijklmn');
StringList.Add('&code = opqrstuvxz');
StringStream.WriteString(StringList.text);

lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
lHTTP.Request.CharSet:= 'utf-8';
lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36';
lHTTP.Request.Method:='POST';
Result:= lHTTP.Post(Url, StringStream);
```

Abaixo o exemplo em PHP disponibilizado pelo ecommerce:

```
$params["consumer_key"] = "### Chave da Aplicação ###";
$params["consumer_secret"] = "### Chave Secreta da Aplicação ###";
$params["code"] = "### Código de Autorização ###";

$url = "https://{api_address}/auth/?".http_build_query($params);

ob_start();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_exec($ch);
```

O que esta faltando ? Ou o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendo muito de Delphi (só tive uma breve experiencia com Object Pascal, o que talvez hoje deva ser um pouco diferente de ambos), mas me parece que isto:

```
StringList.Add('consumer_key = abcdefg');
StringList.Add('&consumer_secret = hijklmn');
StringList.Add('&code = opqrstuvxz');
```

Deveria ser isto:

```
StringList.Add('consumer_key=abcdefg');
StringList.Add('consumer_secret=hijklmn');
StringList.Add('code=opqrstuvxz');
```

Se o `&` e sem espaços separando o `=` da chave e do valor. Isto conforme todos exemplos que encontrei e um pouco da documentação.

Seguindo os exemplos que encontrei e o seu código em PHP me parece que esta executando coisas desnecessárias:

```
lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear; # Não parece necessário
lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; # Não parece necessário (não estou certo)
lHTTP.Request.CharSet:= 'utf-8'; # Não parece necessário
lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'; # Não parece necessário
lHTTP.Request.Method:='POST'; # Não parece necessário
Result:= lHTTP.Post(Url, StringStream);
```

Talvez apenas isto já resolva (já que a API parece que funcionou corretamente com PHP):

```
 lHTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
 IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

StringList := TStringList.Create;
StringList.Add('consumer_key=abcdefg');
StringList.Add('consumer_secret=hijklmn');
StringList.Add('code=opqrstuvxz');

lResult := lHTTP.Post(Url, StringList);
```

Creio que o `StringStream` seja apenas necessário se realmente esta buscando converter para UTF8 (isto se os dados vierem de outras fontes), se o seu `.dpr` estiver salvo como UTF-8 então talvez nem precise disso.

O que provavelmente você deve fazer em scripts futuros é codificar os parametros passados (não tenho certeza se para o `TIdHTTP.Create` isso é realmente necessário, é mais "especulação" minha), pelo que vi os métodos padrões para o uso disto são:

```
uses
  IdURI;

...

TIdURI.URLEncode(valor);
```

Deve ficar algo como:

```
StringList.Add(TIdURI.URLEncode(chave) + '=' + TIdURI.URLEncode(valor));
```

> Note que `HTTPApp.URLEncode` esta em desuso, prefira [`System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding)

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro. Já havia tentando fazer assim antes.

Comment: Desculpe, havia tentando sem o &. Retirei os espaços e o erro mudou: HTTP request failed
401 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Deu certo meu amigo. Muito obrigado. O duro é saber que fiquei dois dias batendo cabeça por causa dos espaços em branco. Mas deu certo, vamos em frente!

Comment: @MarcelloCainelli por favor marque a resposta como correta